# Which Fluentd plugin I should use to listen application logs : in_tcp or in_forward?

Tags: docker, plugins, fluentd

I have Flask app which is streaming some logs in stdout on `localhost:5555`.
I want to listen these logs by dockerized Fluentd, but I'm a bit confused which plugin I should use: in_tcp or in_forward?

Config like this results in error: "Address not available - bind(2) for \"my_ip\" port 5555"

```
<source>
  @type tcp
  tag "tcp.events"
  format none
  bind my_ip
  port 5555
  log-level debug
</source>

<filter **>
  @type stdout
</filter>
```

Config examples for in_forward always have port 24224 in config, so they seem to listen the other fluentds, not to listen an application.

Could you please advice?

Comment: You should use @type forward and send your logs to the server running fluentd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ones which will follow:

Use fluent-logger-language to export your logs to Fluentd server.
Here are all the links:
https://github.com/fluent

Fluentd server config

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  host <if remote>
</source>

<filter **>
  @type stdout
</filter>
```